# Django dropdown list not saving value

Tags: django, dropdown, required

I have a dropdown list box on my django form that shows a correct list of options but the problem I am facing is that the form is not saving the selected value. When I press a submit button, I receive the following error message 'This field is required'. Below is the code that I currently using. I simply can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

**Models.py**

```
 ASSET_TYPE = (
('0','0'),
('1','1'),
('2','2'),
('3','3'),
('4','4')
)
asset = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=ASSET_TYPE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Enquiry
    fields = ['asset']
    asset = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ASSET_TYPE, required=True)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container asset-type">
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="styled-select">
                        <select id="asset" name="asset_type_form">
                            {% for field in form.asset %}
                            <option value="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.choice_label }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                 </div>
             </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: You set the name of your select tag as `asset_type_form` but it should be `asset`...

Comment: It worked. Thanks Abdul. now it passes the value.